# Character limitation according to font size in html li scroller

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

Recently I have tried using [li scroller](http://www.gcmingati.net/wordpress/wp-content/lab/jquery/newsticker/jq-liscroll/scrollanimate.html) to show a ticker message on my webpage.

But I found out that seems like it have limitation in number of character in the ticker message when I use different size of font. When I use a smaller size of font, more character will scroll out. But when I use a bigger size font, less character will scroll out.

I'm just using one list:

```
<ul id="tck_msg">
    <li>Welcome to my place and welcome to this nation</li>
</ul>
```

If I use font size 6vh, the message is "Welcome to my place and welcome". But when I use font size 2vh, the message can show all "Welcome to my place and welcome to this nation".

Do you guys know why?

Answer (score 1):

It's because of ul width. when text is big, this style of parent (overflow:hidden) works and hide additional text.

Solution:
Increase the amount width of ul.